# MySQL split one column into two column

Tags: mysql, sql

Can i split one column into two column in MySql select query??

SELECT * FROM PRODUCT;

```
KEY| PRODUCT |CATEGORY
1  | trip    |city
2  | trip    |ocean
```

into

```
KEY| PRODUCT |CATEGORY1 |CATEGORY2
1  | trip    |city      |ocean
```

Comment: The term for this is pivot and if you search mysql pivot you will find plenty examples.

Comment: That said, consider handling issues of data display in application code